# Is she talking about race?

Tags: перевод

I'm not sure of the context of what the speaker is saying - is she talking about race or general differences in societ? And what is the comment that the narrator follows up with?

(context: http://youtu.be/55bC5zowkFE?t=1h39m6s)

Вот если б я рисовала наше общество, я бы нарисовала круг и много-много разных цветов, много разных пятен. Может быть, у нас было все значительно лучше, если бы одного цвета какого-то, основного, было большинство. 
Но, к сожалению, опасность и цвет один.

**My interpretation:**
Now, if I painted our society I would draw a circle and lots and lots of different colours, lots of different spots. Maybe we'd all be much better if the same colour, the main colour was the majority.

But, unfortunately, the danger and the colour are one. (??)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not about race. She is saying that there are lots of colors now, while it would be better to have a one major color among others.

In terms of race the situation in Russia is opposite - the majority of Russian people are white, so she is definetely not talking about race.

Your russian text is equal to what is said in the film, but I cannot understand why narrator says: "Но, к сожалению, опасность и цвет один".

---

Jwalker notes that the last phrase may be read as "Но, к сожалению, **опасности** цвет один". At this moment the car with big red sticker on its side is crossing the screen. Maybe the narrator means that one major color is not such a good idea after all?

Comment: I think it is _опасности цвет один_--apparently an awkward scene transition referring to the use of red color for alert.

Comment: So perhaps she means colour as in the general variety of society... I guess it's open to interpretation. Thanks!

Comment: "Maybe the narrator means that one major color is not such a good idea after all?" I doubt it. He should have stressed _опасности_ (or is it _опасностей_?), especially with this phrase composition.

Comment: @EtTuBrute To me that is definitely the meaning. Totally nothing to do with race.